# How to perform 2 phase commit in C# Mongodb strongly typed driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the official C# MongoDb strongly typed driver version 2.5.0 to interact with MongoDB.

I have multiple update operations (up to 4) on documents that belongs to different collections that need to be performed in an all-or-nothing pattern (similar to transactions in relational databases).

According to the MongoDB official documentation on this link [Perform Two Phase Commits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/), to perform transactions like updates use 2 phase commits, so my questions are:-

How to achieve that functionality using the C# Mongodb strongly typed driver (please provide code example)?

And if it is not possible please suggest NoSQL Databases that support this functionality.

Comment: Can you wait for MongoDB 4.0? There's a beta program already available which features real ACID transaction stuff. Mind you, the latest version of the C# driver does not even support all features of 3.6 so you will need to work around that, too... https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I can't, even if I waited, when the C# driver will support this major feature? Currently I am considering switching to Martin DB does it support this functionality?

Comment: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/faq/transaction-support

Comment: It seems Martin is a better alternative than Raven DB